# "three hours of you writing", is it an idiomatic expression?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

This video (https://youtu.be/iSV9uohbCjQ?t=258) is saying

> if you're taking something like
>   TOEFL or TOEIC that's going to be an
>   exam, exam instills fear of one or two or
>   three
>   **hours of you writing the test**.

I understand which might mean

> (That) exam instills fear for 3 hours while you are writing the test.

though I've never seen structure like "three hours of you writing" before, is it an idiomatic expression?

Comment: It's a rather odd expression. I assume she means 'fear of having to spend [several] hours taking the written test'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sentence is very poorly written on several levels.  The TOEFL *is* an exam - it's not "going to be an exam." I would say, "An exam like the TOEFL, which might last two or three hours, could instill fear in most students."  You don't "write the test" unless you are the one creating the questions for the students to answer.  In the US, you "take a test."  I've heard British folks say that they "sit for an exam."  You could "write an essay" as part of the examination.